# AngularJS Show/Hide Toggle with NG-Repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list of items which on click should open the single item, but currently when trying to open the single item it opens all items and on second click closed all the items - could somebody please advice where I am going wrong with my code below. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items" layout="column">
  <div layout="row">
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="toggleFilter()">Item {{$index + 1}}</md-button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="toggle">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.toggle = true;
$scope.toggleFilter = function() {
  $scope.toggle = $scope.toggle === false ? true : false;
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit Your code as following:

HTML

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items" layout="column">
  <div layout="row">
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="toggleFilter(item)">Item {{$index + 1}}</md-button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="item.toggle">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.toggleFilter = function(item) {
  item.toggle = !item.toggle;
};
```

Hope that works :)

Answer (score 4):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each item. Each new scope will inherit `toggleFilter` and `toggle` from its parent. Right now you are switching toggle state for parent scope. Thus all child scopes get the same value. If you want to toggle value on child scope simply use `this` instead of `$scope`. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lgs4n9GdXN02ExWCaGG7?p=preview)

```
$scope.toggleFilter = function() {
  this.toggle = !this.toggle
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a parametr inside toggleFilter, and make $scope.toggle an array.
Like that :

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items" layout="column">
  <div layout="row">
    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="toggleFilter($index)">Item {{$index + 1}}</md-button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="toggle[$index]">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.toggle = [];
$scope.toggleFilter = function(inx) {
  $scope.toggle[inx] = $scope.toggle[inx] === false ? true : false;
```

};

Comment: you could simplify with $scope.toggle[inx] = !$scope.toggle[inx]

Answer (score 0):

> hi, so i hope i understood it correctly, but below is a sample code based on your question above. Have taken the liberty to go ahead and change your code a bit.
>
> HTML

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items" layout="column">
<div layout="row">
<md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="toggleFilter()">{{buttonText}} </md-button>
</div>
<div ng-show="toggle">
<!-- Content -->
</div>
</div>
```

> Your JS will be as follows

$scope.toggle= false;

```
$scope.buttonText = "Show";
$scope.toggleFilter = function(){
$scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
$scope.buttonText = "Show";
if(toggle===true){
$scope.buttonText = "Hide";
}
};
```

> I hope this helped.

Comment: How would changing button text help to toggle specific item in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I am sorry, i assumed we had to toggle the button text. But again to toggle to a specific item , we just need to modify the above code as shown below. @YuryTarabanko

Answer (score 0):

> your HTML will be as follows ( only change in HTML is required ).

```
<div ng-show=showMe>
<!--content goes here -->
<ul>
<li ng-hide = "showMe">item1</li>
<li ng-hide = "showMe">item2</li>
<li ng-hide = "showMe">item3</li>
<li ng-hide = "">item4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

> I hope your question is answered. If not please leave a comment i will be really happy to help.